# /var/log/httpd/access_log no longer being written

Tags: centos, logging

On a centos server, For some reason the httpd access log is no longer being written to.  It is located at...

/var/log/httpd/access_log

I have logs in there from a couple of days ago but then they just stop.  What should I be checking to find out why they are no longer being written to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and the files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` for [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directives and enssure that at least one exists that points to `/var/log/httpd/access_log`. Configure (or not) as required.

It's possible that you deleted/recreated the log file and failed to restart apache. In this case httpd will still be writing to the old log file (via the open file descriptor) - restart httpd to fix.

It's possible that the disk/partition is full.